# How to open cordova app with phonenumber link from sms on Android

Tags: android, cordova, sms

When I receive a text message containing a phone number, I want to be able to click on that phone number and have the option to open it with my cordova app. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What is a phone number link to you ? A basic phone number linked by the OS ? Are you targetting a specific OS (iOS, Android, ..) ? in any case : on iOS you can't do what you want to do if it is a basic phone number

Comment: @Niko I am targeting Android. A phone number link is just a phone number sent by SMS. Ex: if i receive this message: "My friends phone number is 450-123-4567" then the phone number gets underlined and when you click on it, you get a list of apps that this phone number can be opened with like Skype. I want my app to appear on this list.